# Joining Multiple Multicast Groups With 1 Socket but Different Ports?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, glibc

I understand that I can bind to INADDR_ANY with 1 port and then join multiple multicast groups.

However, it seems like it is not possible to bind to INADDR_ANY and then join multiple multicast groups with different ports because it seems like the port has to be specified during binding but a socket can only bind once.

Is there a way to get around it so that I can have 1 socket to listen to multiple multicast groups with different ports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving multicast data from different groups on the same socket in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837492/receiving-multicast-data-from-different-groups-on-the-same-socket-in-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it seems like it is not possible to bind to INADDR_ANY

Wrong.

> and then join multiple multicast groups with different ports

Correct.

> because it seems like the port has to be specified during binding but a socket can only bind once.

Correct.

> Is there a way to get around it so that I can have 1 socket to listen to multiple multicast groups with different ports?

No.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer:
[Receiving multicast data from different groups on the same socket in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837492/receiving-multicast-data-from-different-groups-on-the-same-socket-in-linux)

I can't delete my post...so I guess I have to answer myself :(